# use amazon sqs with every client listening for their own messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Im trying to setup an alexa smart home skill, and want to uses aws sqs to have clients listen for messages to turn things on and off. the problem im having is how do i make it so each client can only listen for specific messages meant for them. i want to put a message in the turnOn queue for a specific user with their auth token in the message or something and make it so only the user listening with that auth token can receive that message. Basically i'm trying to set it up so each user can only receive messages meant for their device. Is this possible? i have looked around for tutorials and cant find any documentation on this.

if this is not possible what is the best way to send a message directly to the client telling it to turn of or on. I assume its some sort of MQTT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be possible to create a dedicated SQS queue for each user or device, but this would not be a good design from both a maintainability prospective and also a cost prospective.

There is not a published limit on the number of SQS queues you can have in an account, but SQS is billed based on polls so having lots of devices polling their dedicated queues would get very expensive.

However, from a security prospective this is possible to secure this approach.  You could put an API in front of SQS that would authorize a token and then poll the appropriate SQS queue.  Alternatively, you could use STS to vend temporarily credentials to a specific queue using an API to avoid the middle processing.

I would only recommend this approach for toy examples such as a hackathon or building something for personal use only.  Even then only because it is fairly simple to code and understand how it works, but this really isn't efficient.

---

The appropriate solution to this problem would be to use AWS IoT.  This provides a managed MQTT implementation that you can register devices on and assign permissions to the appropriate topics.  The billing here is per message.

There is more to setup and understand using AWS IoT but overall the approach is more efficient for large number of devices and is also more scalable and production ready.